# mysql inserting values: echoing $profile_id from link one through til mysql function?

Tags: php, mysql

There's basically pictures on my users profile page that people need permission to see.
I'm basically getting the user to click one link to open a jQuery window and then from within that jQuery window the user needs to click another link and this runs the mysql function and is suppose to  insert the user_id which is the users $_session['user_id'] into the table 'ptb_permissions' and the profile id of the user whose pictures that user is trying to see.
So this means the users $profile_id needs to be inserted into 'private_id.

At the moment though only the user_id is being inserted. can someone please show me where I'm going wrong I think I'm loosing the echo at the first link, I don't think I've written the code write here:

```
<?php            
    $photo = "data/private_photos/0/_default.jpg";
    if (!file_exists($photo)) {
        $photo = "data/photos/0/_default.jpg";
    }
    $thumb = "data/private_photos/0/_default.jpg";
    if (!file_exists($thumb)) {
        $thumb = "data/photos/0/_default.jpg";
    }
    echo
    "<li><a href=\"privileges.php?to=\"$profile_id\" rel=\"shadowbox;height=300;width=500\" title=\"$profile[2]'s Photo's\"><img src=\"$thumb\" width=\"90\" height=\"90\" alt=\"<strong>{$profile[2]}'s Photos</strong>\"  /></a></li>";

    ?>
```

after this link is clicked this then opens up a jquery window and the user needs to click:

```
<a href="request_priv_pix.php?to=?to=<?php echo "$profile_id"; ?>" class="link">Let Me See</a>
```

then i run my function:

```
<?php 

// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    require('includes/_config/connection.php');
// LOAD FUNCTIONS
    require('includes/functions.php');
    require_once("includes/session.php");
// GET IP ADDRESS
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


    session_start();

    if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
    $user_to_id = $_GET['to'];


}


if (!isset($_GET['to']))
    exit('No user specified.');

$user_id = $_GET['to'];





$sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_permissions (id, user_id, private_id) VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$user_to_id."');";
            mysql_query($sql, $connection);

            echo "<div class=\"infobox2\"><strong>Your message has successfully been sent.</strong></div>";


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but the link syntax is not correct:

```
request_priv_pix.php?to=?to=...
```

May be:

```
request_priv_pix.php?to=...
```

Comment: thanks i didnt notice that, have fixed the typo and still no profile id beinig entered any ideas please

Comment: make some degug of your code. Use var_dump($_GET) to watch the content of this array and be sure that the parameter is being initialized.
If user_id and private_id are integers you don't need use quotes in the sql syntax... "insert into....values(null,".$_SESSION['user_id']...
In the opened window be sure that the link is correctly written viewing the source.
I no have more ideas.Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have a typo in second link?

```
href="request_priv_pix.php?to=?to="
```

Comment: ok i didnt notice that thanks, but i fixed it and still no profile id being entered. any ideas please

Comment: I dont know if you have caught this yet, but I just noticed that in your first link you put: a href=\"privileges.php?to=\"$profile_id\"... you escaped the first double quote after to=, so the url will literally be privelages.php?to="$profile_id

Comment: I think you want to concatenate this as "to=".$profile_id."\"